# ascending and descending order in c

Tags: c++, c

I am a beginner in programming languages like c,c++ and java
I really need someone to guide me on this one
So the problem is:
This code, I wrote on borland c++

1)

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = i; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (number[i] > number[j])
        {
        a =  number[i];
        number[i] = number[j];
        number[j] = a;
        }
    }
}
```

2)

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (number[i] > number[j])
        {
        a =  number[i];
        number[i] = number[j];
        number[j] = a;
        }
   }
}
```

In the first code the logic in the inner for loop j=i will sort the numbers in ascending order,in the second code the logic in the inner for loop j=0 will sort the numbers in descending order.

Now my question is: why do the logic j=i sorts the number in ascending order and why the logic j=0 sorts the number in descending order, can someone explain the working concepts and the difference between the logic j=i and j=0?

Comment: Get paper pencil and your debugger.  Start stepping through the code, making notes of the var values at each stage.

Comment: you didn't *write* this code. This are examples from a schoolbook. You should ask your teacher.

Comment: Excuse me bro!! but i did write this code @KarmaEDV

Comment: @MartinJames I already tried those steps but still i couldn't figure it out, are there any other alternative ??

Comment: @Nikshay Yes, try becoming a cook or gardener

Comment: I wonder, how did you come up with this code? What was your reasoning that lead to writing this code? I mean, most likely you didnt randomly hit the keyboard and when you looked at the screen, you suddenly got this code. What was your logic, when writing this?

Comment: @tobi303 As i already mentioned i am a beginner in c and c++, and the real purporse of writing this code is to practice and enhance my skills in programming language, i mean i write a lot of simple codes to enhance my skill step by step, so when i wrote this code for ascending order with j=i my friend suggested changing j=i to j=0 this lead to sorting by descending order... can u explain my problem??

Comment: Print the sequence in each inner loop, you will get an idea.
For your Information, printf is a quick debugging tool

Comment: @KarmaEDV yeah thanks for the advice Dennis Ritchie

Comment: @Nikshay what?  You DID write the code, and then posted on SO asking how/why it works?  Can you see how I have a problem comprehending that scenario?

Comment: 'my friend suggested changing j=i to j=0 this lead to sorting by descending order.'  why don't you ask your friend to explain it?

Comment: @Nikshay You're welcome. Please feel free to take my advice seriously.

Comment: @MartinJames that's the problem, he just wanted me to simply change it from j=i to j=0 to see what effect it would produce, and it resulted in descending order!!!

Comment: Thank u bro, I ll give it a try!!!

Answer (score 1):

What happens in the second code differently from the first is that the loop starts sorting the numbers in ascending order (just like the first code) but because the second (inner loop) compares the current number with the already sorted numbers in the beginning (which are the smallest) swaps places. Thus we end up with the largest numbers first. Look at it as if the first code is the first step of the second code: first put the numbers in order and then in descending order.

Comment: Bro, the thing is: the above 2 code blocks are not in the same program, the first one is for ascending order, and the 2nd is for descending order, what i mean to say is, i did not use the above 2 blocks in a single program!!!